# Converting a number into the format minutes:seconds.hundreths in bash script?

Tags: bash

I am implementing the top command. I need to calculate the Time+ field just like the top command.
As of right now, I am getting the utime and stime then I put the system to sleep and then getting it these values again. I add the 4 quantities and divide the total by 100 which gives me a number. Here is the code for reference:

```
oldutime=$(awk '{print $14}' /proc/$word/stat )
oldstime=$(awk '{print $15}' /proc/$word/stat )

newutime=$(awk '{print $14}' /proc/$word/stat )
newstime=$(awk '{print $15}' /proc/$word/stat )

total_time=`expr $oldutime + $oldstime + $newutime + $newstime`

timee=$((total_time / 100))
```

After this I need to format this number so that it looks like the output of TIME+ field (minutes: seconds.hunderehts) in the top program and I need help doing that. I was looking at the `date` command but couldn't figure it out.

EDIT:

Desired for format: 0:00.24 (minutes:seconds.hunderdths)
Output: 360

Comment: Show $total_time and your desired output.

Comment: Don't use `expr`; use `$((...))` instead. Note that neither one does floating-point arithmetic, though.

Comment: From `man proc` I read that the fields 14 and 15 of `/proc/[pid]/stat` are _measured in clock ticks_, which I barely know what it is, but I bet its length in time is not a physical constant, so you cannot convert it to a time by multiplying by a number; you then integer-divide this time by 100. So what does `timee` contain in your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following scriptlet can be used to format time in milliseconds:

Code assume total_time is calculated - either per OP question, or modified for comments (using $((...))) instead of expr.

```
# Calculate total time in tick
total_time=...
ticks_per_sec=$(getconf CLK_TCK)
# Seconds times 100
s100=$((total_time*100/ticks_per_sec))
printf '%d:%02d.%02d\n' $((s100/100/60)) $((s100/100%60)) $((s100%100))
```